# insert a newline for a single column in bash

Tags: bash

I have file in bash where the lines don't match up.

I need to remove the title "Product + Region" and move the information from the left up one line.
But in my example output below hostname01 should be on the same line as HOST EU.

```
 Product + Region                            hostname01
 HOST EU                                     hostname02
                                             hostname03
                                             hostname04
HOST US                                      hostname05
```

The problem I am having is that list is of hundreds of hosts and they are all mis matched because of the first line.

I was trying to awk each coloumn into different files, insert a line into the right side. But the problem is not all of the hosts have a "Product + Region".

I would really appreciate some advice.

I tried `grep -v -o "Product + Region"` but it didn't work. :s

Comment: The problem is that whenever you have a `Product + Region` entry on a line you need to delete that and replace it with the `HOST XX` from the following line?

Comment: No so when I delete Product + Region, I need all the information on the left to move up one. so Host EU should be on the same line as hostname01 and HOST US should be on the same line as hostname04. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: And `Product + Region` can occur more than once in the file and you need to shift up one extra line for each `P + R` you remove?

Comment: No, It only occurs at the top of the file. So just need to remove it once.

Comment: Is this file space delimited and manually column aligned? Is that alignment/etc. important to retain? The hostname is always one word? The `P + R` is/can be two (or more) words?

Comment: Sample input and output can help me more .. Can u plz share if possible

Comment: P+R will only ever be "Host EU" or "Host US" or "Host APAC" or nothing. hostname can be more than one word. It is important that the hostname and P+R to be on the same line. Apart from that the alignment doesn't matter.

Comment: If this is a one-time thing, you'd be best served by loading it up in a spreadsheet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just need to remember the host from the previous line.

```
awk '
  NR > 1 {print substr($0,1, 25) prev}
  {prev = substr($0,26)}
  END {printf "%25s%s\n", "", prev}
' file
```

```
 HOST EU                                     hostname01
                                             hostname02
                                             hostname03
HOST US                                      hostname04
                                             hostname05
```